# Using rewrite mod in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to write a rewrite rule to do the following: if any of the following files exist on the server as a static html file in a specific directory then I'd like .htaccess to serve that static file. Otherwise, I'd like the id (**first number** after the **.com/** and before the **first hyphen**) to be passed as a query parameter to `www.gallery.com/index.php`

Redirect should occur for the following URLs if it doesn't exist as a static HTML page.

```
 www.gallery.com/2-swimming.html
 www.gallery.com/2
 gallery.com/2
```

Below is my entire .htaccess file

```
<Files .htaccess> 
   order allow,deny 
   deny from all 
</Files> 


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENANE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENANE} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything wrong with my rewrite condition.(I'm having a hard time). Also what is an efficient way to grab the id incase of a redirect.

Comment: Your rewriterule will only kick in if the user tries to hit a `.html` address, so your `gallery.com/2` would never match: there's no `.html` and no `-` in the address.

Comment: How can I fix the rewrite for both `gallery.com/2` and 'gallery.com/2-word1-word2.html'

Comment: 2-word1-word2 would work, because `2` will match against the `([0-9]+)` portion, and `word1-word2` will get caught by `(.*)`. It looks like you only care about the actual NUMBER at the start of the address, so why not `Rewriterule ^([0-9]+) /index.php?id=$1` instead? That'd capture ONLY the number and ignore everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just always pass everything to `index.php`?

PHP is a lot better at manipulating strings than `.htaccess`

The `-f` line already takes care of existing static files. (And `-d` for directories)

---

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rule matches and captures everything.

Comment: How can I pass the entire parameter as a string if the html static pages doesn't exist. Also, how do I retrieve it and manipulate it to find the id. I'm so sorry. This is my first project.